Adding words to a WPF spell checker
I have this WPF control inserted into a WinForms:
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Forms.Integration;
using System.Windows.Forms.Design;


[Designer(typeof(ControlDesigner))]
class SpellBox : ElementHost
{
    public SpellBox()
    {
        box = new TextBox();
        base.Child = box;
        box.TextChanged += (s, e) => OnTextChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
        box.SpellCheck.IsEnabled = true;
        box.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto;
        this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
    }
    public override string Text
    {
        get { return box.Text; }
        set { box.Text = value; }
    }
    [DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool Multiline
    {
        get { return box.AcceptsReturn; }
        set { box.AcceptsReturn = value; }
    }
    [DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool WordWrap
    {
        get { return box.TextWrapping != TextWrapping.NoWrap; }
        set { box.TextWrapping = value ? TextWrapping.Wrap : TextWrapping.NoWrap; }
    }
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    public new UIElement Child
    {
        get { return base.Child; }
        set { /* Do nothing to solve a problem with the serializer !! */ }
    }
    private TextBox box;
}

It works fine, but if I press the right mouse button it doesn't give me the option to add the selected word.
How can I use a custom dictionary and add my own words? (This is my first time using a WPF control in WinForms)
Thanks everyone.
